# Volume between $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=x+y$

Tags: analysis

I need to find the volume between two functions $ z=x^2+y^2 $ and $ z=x + y $. I converted the functions into polar coordinates and ended up with next integral:

\begin{cases}
z=z \newline
x=r\cos(\phi) \newline
y=r\sin(\phi) \newline 
I=r
\end{cases}
$$
\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{1}_0\int^{2}_0rdzdrd\phi=...=2\pi
$$

It does not seem correct, because I estimated that rectangular with height $2$ and sides $\sqrt2$ around the shape has volume of $4$, which is less than $2\pi$. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Your integration limits don't look right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volume is bounded between $z=x^{2}+y^{2}$ and $z=x+y$.

So $$\iint_{S}\int_{x^{2}+y^{2}}^{x+y}\,dz\,dy\,dx=\iint_{S}x+y-x^{2}-y^{2}\,dxdy$$

Where $S$ is the region enclosed by the curve $x+y=x^{2}+y^{2}$ which is the same as $(x-0.5)^{2}+(y-0.5)^{2}=0.5$

Thus you have $$\iint_{S}(\frac{1}{2}-(x-\frac{1}{2})^{2}-(y-\frac{1}{2})^{2})\,dxdy$$

Now you substitute $x=u+\frac{1}{2} , y=v+\frac{1}{2}$ to have

$$\iint_{T}(\frac{1}{2}-u^{2}-v^{2})\,dudv$$ where $T$ is the circular region $u^{2}+v^{2}\leq\frac{1}{2}$ .

Now you use polar coordinates to have

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}((\frac{1}{2}-r^{2})r\,d\theta dr $$